# Insert inline image to automatic email response via google forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to insert a company logo into an automatic email that is sent out to customers who fill in a form via our website (which is linked to google forms). I am using the script to generate the automatic email and I can't seem to find out how to insert an inline image. I'm currently linking to an online image we have and it doesn't work well because the aspect ratio seems to vary depending on which device you are using. [image: this is what it should look like]

Could someone please amend my code below so that it works with an inline image. Many thanks.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc  Limits the script to only accessing the current form.
 */

var DIALOG_TITLE = 'Example Dialog';
var SIDEBAR_TITLE = 'Example Sidebar';

/**
 * Adds a custom menu with items to show the sidebar and dialog.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed; calls onOpen() to ensure menu creation and
 * any other initializion work is done immediately.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger.
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar. The sidebar structure is described in the Sidebar.html
 * project file.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle(SIDEBAR_TITLE);
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

/**
 * Opens a dialog. The dialog structure is described in the Dialog.html
 * project file.
 */
function showDialog() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog')
      .evaluate()
      .setWidth(350)
      .setHeight(170);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, DIALOG_TITLE);
}

/**
 * Appends a new form item to the current form.
 *
 * @param {Object} itemData a collection of String data used to
 *     determine the exact form item created.
 */
function addFormItem(itemData) {
  // Use data collected from sidebar to manipulate the form.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  switch (itemData.type) {
    case 'Date':
      form.addDateItem().setTitle(itemData.name);
      break;
    case 'Scale':
      form.addScaleItem().setTitle(itemData.name);
      break;
    case 'Text':
      form.addTextItem().setTitle(itemData.name);
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Queries the form DocumentProperties to determine whether the formResponse
 * trigger is enabled or not.
 *
 * @return {Boolean} True if the form submit trigger is enabled; false
 *     otherwise.
 */
function getTriggerState() {
  // Retrieve and return the information requested by the dialog.
  var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  return properties.getProperty('triggerId') != null;
}

/**
 * Turns the form submit trigger on or off based on the given argument.
 *
 * @param {Boolean} enableTrigger whether to turn on the form submit
 *     trigger or not
 */
function adjustFormSubmitTrigger(enableTrigger) {
  // Use data collected from dialog to manipulate form.

  // Determine existing state of trigger on the server.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var triggerId = properties.getProperty('triggerId');

  if (!enableTrigger && triggerId != null) {
    // Delete the existing trigger.
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(form);
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      if (triggers[i].getUniqueId() == triggerId) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
    properties.deleteProperty('triggerId');
  } else if (enableTrigger && triggerId == null) {
    // Create a new trigger.
    var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('respondToFormSubmit')
        .forForm(form)
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
    properties.setProperty('triggerId', trigger.getUniqueId());
  }
}

/**
 * Responds to form submit events if a form summit trigger is enabled.
 * Collects some form information and sends it as an email to the form creator.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter created by a form
 *      submission; see
 *      https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events
 */
function respondToFormSubmit(e) {
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var message = 'There have been ' + form.getResponses().length +
        ' response(s) so far. Latest Response:\n';
    var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
      var itemTitle = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle();
      var itemResponse = JSON.stringify(itemResponses[i].getResponse());
      message += itemTitle + ': ' + itemResponse + '\n';
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(
        Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
        'Form response received for form ' + form.getTitle(),
        message,
        {name: 'Forms Add-on Template'});
  }
}


/* Send Confirmation Email with Google Forms */


function Initialize() {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendConfirmationMail")
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();

}



function SendConfirmationMail(e) {

    try {

        var ss, bcc, sendername, subject, columns, submitter;
        var message, value, textbody, sender, aliases;

        // Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
        var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();

        // This is your email address and you will be in the CC
        bcc = aliases[0];

        // This will show up as the sender's name
        sendername = "The Flatser Team";

        // This is the submitter's name
        submitter = e.namedValues["Full Name"].toString();

        // This is the submitter's email address
        sender = e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString();

        // Optional but change the following variable
        // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
        subject = "Please select a call time";

        // This is the body of the auto-reply
        message = "Dear "+ submitter + ", <br/><br/>Thank you for completing our form. Please fill in your availability for a telephone or skype call using the link below.<br/><br/>https://calendly.com/bcwolf/flatser-skype-call/06-23-2015<br/><br/><br/>Kind regards,<br/><br/>--<br/><br/><b>The Flatser Team</b><br/><a href='www.flatser.com'>www.flatser.com</a><br/><br/><img width='10%' height='10%' src='http://flatser.com/img/logo1.png'/>";

        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        columns = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];


        textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");

        GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                            {bcc: bcc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message, from: aliases[0] });

    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set different widths according to different devices in your email using media queries.

In your case, i would prepend the `<style>` in your message variable for function `SendConfirmationMail` and add class to `img` tag inside the message variable which will then look as follows:

BODY OF MESSAGE ( assuming you need 100px width logo on mobile and 200px width on bigger screens. Also note do not set the height as it will ruin the aspect ratio if you calculate it incorrectly)

```
 // This is the body of the auto-reply
 // This is what i would add 
 message = "<style> @media (max-width:499px) { .logo__flaster { width: 100px; } @media (min-width:500px) { .logo__flaster { width: 200px; } </style>"

 // This is same, i have only removed width from img and added class logo__flaster which i used in the style above.
 message += "Dear "+ submitter + ", <br/><br/>Thank you for completing our form. Please fill in your availability for a telephone or skype call using the link below.<br/><br/>https://calendly.com/bcwolf/flatser-skype-call/06-23-2015<br/><br/><br/>Kind regards,<br/><br/>--<br/><br/><b>The Flatser Team</b><br/><a href='www.flatser.com'>www.flatser.com</a><br/><br/><img class='logo__flaster' src='http://flatser.com/img/logo1.png'/>";
```

Please read [Media Queries in HTML Email](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email) article for more information, Also see more [media queries templates](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) if you want to customise more to a specific screen.